# CSS / LESS hexagon avatar for WBBoard

Tags: css, hex, less, avatar

ATM our woltlab burning board displays the user avatar with the following LESS code as round images, which is pretty nice.

```
.sidebar > div > fieldset > .userAvatarImage img {
    border-radius: 0 !important;
}

.message .messageSidebar .userAvatarImage img,
img[alt~="Benutzer-Avatarbild"],
img[alt~="User Avatar"] {
    border-radius: 200px;
```

### }

```
.messageGroupList .columnAvatar .myAvatar {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0)
}

.framed > canvas, 
.framed > img, 
.framed > .icon {
    border: 1px solid darken(@wcfContainerBackgroundColor,8%);
    border-radius: 200px;
```

### }

```
#topMenu:not(.fixed) .headerUserAvatar {
    left: 12px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -33px;
}

#topMenu:not(.fixed) .headerUserAvatar img {
    padding: 2px;
    border: 0 !important;
    height: 60px !important;
    width: 60px !important;
}

#topMenu.fixed .headerUserAvatar {
    left: 12px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
}

#topMenu.fixed .headerUserAvatar img {
    padding: 2px;
    border: 0 !important;
    height: 24px !important;
    width: 24px !important;
}

.pageHeaderUser #topMenu.fixed .userPanelItems {
    margin-left: 48px;
```

### }

My new concept would be to display the user avatar as a hexagon which has same side lenghts. The hexagon would have to be with one 120° ankle pointing to the top. I have no clue how to implement that. Does anybody know how to?
Sorry if I described it not that good - it is hard to explain writing in english for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a quick research with the keywords `css` & `shape`, I found a **css only, supported everywhere** solution on :

https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

Or you can use **SVG** :

```
<svg width="100%" height="300">
  <defs>
     <pattern id="image" x="0" y="0" height="300" width="300">
       <image width="300" height="300" xlink:href="http://placekitten.com/306/306"></image>
    </pattern>
  </defs>

  <polygon points="150,0 280,75 280,225 150,300 20,225 20,75" fill="url('#image')"></polygon>

</svg>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8but9nc4/2/

Or use the **CSS clip-path** property directly (works only in Webkit browsers) :

```
clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0% 75%, 0% 25%);
```

(You might have to add *-webkit-* prefix).

These are great tools available online to help you :

[Clippy](http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/) or 
[Clip Path Generator](http://cssplant.com/clip-path-generator)